# Determine $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

> Determine $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{z}}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_m)$

I've already described $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)$ but I am struggling with the simpler version of the problem above. I know I once again look at where 1 is mapped to i.e $\phi(1)=a$ and we know $\phi(0)=0$ so $\phi(0) = \phi(n) = na = 0$ but I'm blanking on what this tells me about a.

Can someone point me in the right direction to finish the proof?

Comment: There's no $n$ here. It tells you nothing about $a$, so all $m$ possibilities count. Btw $\Bbb Z$ is the *free* group on one generator, which means exactly this.

Comment: @Berci can you elaborate a little further? I'm a little lost with your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** There's no restriction to $a$ other than being an element of $\Bbb Z_m$.

Prove more generally that there's always a bijection
$$\hom(\Bbb Z, G)\simeq G$$
for any group $G$.

Comment: Thank you this cleared it up, I didn't even think to generalize it.